# Scala Play framework 2.5 - Elegant way to populate combobox calling a defined route or controller

Tags: scala, frontend, playframework-2.5

I'm new to the Scala world and FE development.

I have a play application in Scala that implements a call to an external api that returns a Seq[(String, String)]. 
I would like to use this seq to populate a select input element in a template.

My question is if there's an elegant way of doing this? I have only found messy javascript/jquery calls that I don't even understand :/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Play comes with some "helpers" that will generate some html code for you to do this. `@select` is the name of the method for the input select. More details can be found [on the playframework Scala Forms page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms).

You can also generate it manually if you prefer. Example of both [in this recent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435632/the-role-of-tuple-in-playframework/40697946#40697946).