# The role of Tuple in PlayFramework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

Now I'm using play2.2.1, and I know Java, but I don't know Scala.
And if you learn PlayFramework even just a little bit, you will know Scala is used in some extent in the framework.    This is just a background about me.  The question is why is Tuple2 used in below code although the number of passing values is one not plural.

This is the controller's code:

```
//Action for making a message
    public static Result add() {
        Form<Message> f = new Form(Message.class);
        List<Member> mems = Member.find.select("name").findList();
        List<Tuple2<String, String>> opts =
                            new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, String>>();
        for(Member mem: mems) {
            opts.add(new Tuple2(mem.name, mem.name));
        }
        return ok(add.render("fill-in form", f, opts));
    }
```

This is the Model's code:

```
@Entity
public class Member extends Model {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required(message = "This item is Required")
    public String name;

    @Email(message = "Please Fill in a message")
    public String mail;

    public String tel;

    public static Finder<Long, Member> find = new Finder<Long, Member>(Long.class, Member.class);

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String ids = "{id:";
        for (Message m: messages) {
            ids += " " + m.id;
        }
        ids += "}";
        return ("[id:" + id + ", message:" + ids + ", name:" + name + ", mail:" + mail + ", tel:" + tel + "]");
    }

    public static Member findByName(String input) {
        return Member.find.where().eq("name", input).findList().get(0);
    }
}
```

This is the View's code:

```
@(msg:String, form1: Form[models.Message], opts: List[Tuple2[String, String]])

@main("Sample page") {
    <h1>ADD MESSAGE</h1>
    <p>@msg</p>
    @helper.form(action = routes.Application.create) {

    @(helper.select (
        field = form1("name"),
        options = opts
        ))

    @(helper.textarea (
        field = form1("message")
        ))

    <input type="submit">
    }
}
```

Again, why is Tuple2, which contains two String values, used despite one value passed from the controller to the view?
If the information I showed here is not enough, please give me a comment.

Comment: Scala in not used in "Some extent". Play Framework is written in Scala and is mostly Scala. And also has a Java API. And `tuple` in one of the most natural structures for `key-value pairs` and that particular `list` looks like a list of `key-value pairs`. And I feel that this line - `opts.add(new Tuple2(mem.name, mem.name))` should have been - `opts.add(new Tuple2("name", mem.name))`

Comment: Indeed, I attempted to changed as you said. And it works well.  So, what is the meaning of the first argument of Tuple here?  Your code you showed is meaningful and persuasive. However, "opts.add(new Tuple2(mem.name, mem.name))" is also okay, but why?   The first argument doesn't have any important meaning?

Comment: Basically `new Tuple2("abc", "def")` will create an instance of `Tuple2[String, String]`. `Tuple` is a generic structure like `List` or `Map`. Take a `Map[String, String]` for example. A `Map[String, String]` does not have any meaning in itself. Its just a holder for `values` mapped by a `key`. It will always be about how are you going to use that Map.

Comment: I see.     I can understand what you say.   Although I said it worked well,now I have confirmed that the compilation fails when I write like what you said right now.   That means "opts.add(new Tuple2(mem.name, mem.name))" is okay, but "opts.add(new Tuple2("name", mem.name))" causes the error.  The error message is like this: `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`  at `return Member.find.where().eq("name", input).findList().get(0);`    This means passing the variable "name" fails somehow when the code is yours.     So, can you explain?

Comment: That code is where you are using your `Tuple`, so you have to use it according to how you created it. Its just like when you have a `Map` which contains value `def` for key `abc`, you will have to do a `map.get("def")` to get `abc`; anything else will not work.

Comment: Now lets get back to why you are getting this particular error. A `select` in `html` contains a list of options. Where each option contains a `show-value` and a `value`. `show-value` is shown as text in your select box and `value` is used as the value of that select box whenever a particular option is chosen. Now Play's templates' `helper.select` takes two params - first the name for select box and a list of `(value, show-value)` tuples. So... In this particular case your `opts.add(new Tuple2(mem.name, mem.name))` was correct. I hope you understand things now.

Comment: If I wrote `opts.add(new Tuple2("name", mem.name))`, all show-value should be `"name"`, so it is not good because users can't differentiate.  That is why the compiler gave the error.  Am I right?

Comment: No... the `value` will be `"name"`. And you do not have a compilation error. that is a run-time exception. The explanation is that `Member.find.where().eq("name", input).findList()` gives you a list of all `members` whose `name` is equal to the `input`. And this `input` is that `value` of your select box. Thus when the `value` (and hence `input`) is just `"name"` that list of `members` whose name is equal to `"name"` is empty. And hence when you do `get(0)` to get first element of this empty list, you are getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException ` error.

Comment: I see.  The order of the `Tuple2`'s arguments is that first one is `show-value` and second one is `value`. So, if I write `opts.add(new Tuple2("name", mem.name))`, the all values become `"name"` whatever you choose. Therefore at the statement `Member.find.where().eq("name", input).findList() `, I have gotten the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.   I'm so sorry for many askings, but  is my comprehension right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The role of a tuple is to provide multiple values in a single instance. Perhaps it's a bit like an unnamed class? To summarise the comments and give a clear example, the structure of the `<option>` tag in a `<select>` structure is

```
<option value="internal-value">shown-value</option>
```

We use it often for foreign key situations - the foreign key value is in "internal-value" and the name or other attribute from the linked table is in the shown-value.

If you use the play helper @select to generate it, you should provide a `Seq` of tuple2s - i.e. two strings for each option. The first for the internal value, and the second for the displayed value. I use a `defining` but that is just one way to do it. For example:

```
@defining(for (a <- AppType.all()) yield (a.id.toString,a.name)) { appTypeList =>
    @select(
        apiForm("forApp"),
        appTypeList,
        'class -> "form-control",
        '_default -> "-- None Selected --",
        '_label -> "App Type"
    )
}
```

You can generate it yourself manually if you have some special needs or reason not to use the helper (or you can write your own helper :) ). For example:

```
<select name="forApiType" id="forApiType">
    @ApiType.all().map { a =>
      <option value="@a.id" @if(a.id==apiType.id) {selected}>
        @a.name
      </option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: In your explanation, I can't understand the point of foreign key.  Of course, I know what a foreign key is, but I can't understand.  Please give me supplemental information.  And in your code, there seems to be no "Tupple".  So, I'm confused. You showed the code because you explained "Tupple"?

Comment: `yield (a.id.toString,a.name)` produces a list of Tuple2s of type (String,String), which is needed for the @select helper. In a foreign key situation, say fk_country_id column on an address table, you want to show a list of country names (the shown-value), but on the form you want to store the country_id (the internal value). Does that help explain? (In my second section of code, I don't use tuples.)